# Copy file using just Mach and Hurd functions

Tags: c, debian, gnu, mach, microkernel

I am working on Debian GNU/Hurd with Mach. I have been asked to write a program that given two arguments (origen file and destination file), copies one file into the other. I'm asked to use just Mach and Hurd calls, such as `mach_port_deallocate`, `mach_task_self`, `file_name_lookup`, `io_read, io_write`.

I'm new developing Hurd and I'm really lost, any help would be preciated.